# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSURL' with an argument list of type '(fileURLWithPath: NSURL)'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I upgraded my code for Swift 2, here I got an error:

Cannot invoke initializer for type `NSURL` with an argument list of type `(fileURLWithPath: NSURL)`

Here's the code:

```
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] 
    let soundFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docsDir).URLByAppendingPathComponent("sound.caf")
    let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)
    //The error goes here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax of `fileURLWithPath`:

```
public init(fileURLWithPath path: String)
```

Which means it only accept `String` as argument. And you are passing `NSURL` as an argument.

And you can solve it this way:

```
let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
let soundFilePath = (docsDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("sound.caf")
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)
```

And here is extension if you want to use:

```
extension String {

    func stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: String) -> String {

        return (self as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
    }
}
```

And you can use it this way:

```
let soundFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("sound.caf")
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)
```

Comment: In Swift 2 `stringByAppendingPathComponent` is removed, that's why I upgraded my code. But this is very useful anyway.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create an NSURL from an NSURL object, there is no initializer for that. To create the URL properly just replace

```
let soundFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docsDir).URLByAppendingPathComponent("sound.caf")
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)
```

with

```
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docsDir).URLByAppendingPathComponent("sound.caf")
```