# How to exclude file from backup in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I had this working great with Swift 1.2 as I used the filePath as a string. Now Swift 2 wants us all to use URL paths I can't get this to work even though i'm reading through their docs.

I have;

```
var fileName = "myRespondusCSV.csv"

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

let documentsURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)


if let documentPath: NSURL = documentsURL.first as NSURL! {

    filePath = documentPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        print(filePath)        
    } else {
        fileManager.createFileAtPath(filePath!.path!,
                                     contents: ("" as String).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
                                     attributes:nil)
        print("file has been created")
    }
}

func excludeFileFromBackup() {

    var error:NSError?
    //var fileToExcludeh = NSURL.fileReferenceURL(filePath!)

    var fileToExcludeh = fileURLWithPath(filePath)

    let success = fileToExcludeh.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: &error)
}
```

I'm getting a 'Use of unresolved identifier 'fileURLWithPath'!

Should I be using an absolute URL path?

Comment: fileURLWithPath is not a (global) function, but a method of NSURL. There are many examples on SO how to use that method, a recent one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665508/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-nsurl-with-an-argument-list-of-type-fileu.

Comment: The commented code ` //var fileToExcludeh = NSURL.fileReferenceURL(filePath!)` seems correct, then why did you comment that ?

Comment: The example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665508/ cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-nsurl-with-an-argument-list-of-type-fileudoes not (as yet) have an answer. Swift 2 has removed the stringByAppendingPathComponent which means I need to create the path as a URL instead. To answer Midhun MP; the commented code threw another error 'function value was used as a property; add () to call'. There is no function with this name in my code 'fileToExcludeh'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
        do {
            try filePath.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
        } catch _{
            print("Failed")
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! just came back to this; your solution was better!

Comment: It can be written in a single line: try? filePath.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)

Comment: I get `Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'`

Answer (score 18):

Swift 4 if anyone needs it:

```
var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
try? fileUrl.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Swift 4

Answer (score 5):

This is working for Swift 3.
URL must be a `var`.

```
let urls:[URL] = FileManager.default.urls(for:FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in:FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)
let appDirectory:URL = urls.last!
var fileUrl:URL = appDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myFile")

var resourceValues:URLResourceValues = URLResourceValues()
resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true

do
{
    try fileUrl.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
}
catch let error
{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Is the given `fileUrl` modified or are there just other technical reasons for it to be a var? I looked at the source (https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSURL.swift), but could not figure it out for sure.

Comment: @Klaas URL has to be mutable as you are modifying its resource values.

Comment: ah, makes sense. I  did assume that those were not cached and directly written to the file system.

Answer (score 2):

The code that runs for me in swift 5 is...

```
var file: URL = <# your URL file #>
do {
   var res = URLResourceValues()
   res.isExcludedFromBackup = true
   try file.setResourceValues(res)
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Of course you can put this in a function or an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my resolution for it on **Swift 3**

```
func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(URL:NSURL) -> Bool {
    var success: Bool

    do {
        try URL.setResourceValue(true, forKey:URLResourceKey.isExcludedFromBackupKey)
        success = true
    } catch let error as NSError {
        success = false
        print("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent!) from backup \(error)");
    }
    return success
}
```