# Prevent app from migrating file between app versions

Tags: ios

I know [there's a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32807331/183726) of excluding a file from being backed up to iTunes / iCloud. However, what I want to do is prevent the file from being migrated when the user updates the app directly from the device via the AppStore.

Is this supported by the operating system? I can't find any documentation on it and the existence of [this](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTMigration) library seems to suggest that it's not supported natively.

Comment: My first thought is why would this be needed? I case of change to a core data model you can version the model. You could do the same for any file you store, so on launch of the app you check the file version and decide to delete it.

Comment: i can always do it manually but i was wondering if it's supported by the OS in the same way as for backup.

in our case we store a json representation of a file on disk using `Encodable` and i'd like to exclude it from migrations to ensure we don't have to deal with model version conflicts

Comment: I do not think there is such a way to this. Would be a good option, but I think you will be stuck doing it deletion yourself.